# Discard socket receive buffer

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to time how long it takes to get a response of known size from a server, and I'm also trying to squeeze every bit of speed I can out of my program as it's handling a tremendous volume of these connections.

I have SO_RCVLOWAT set to the size of the data I'm expecting, then epoll edge-triggering.

My question is: can I command the socket to reset its receive buffer state to empty without actually having to read in all the data? I'm trying to avoid having to do a copy as I don't actually need the response data.

I can be sure that only the expected data size will be available on the socket at any time, so I'm not concerned with messing up future reads; I just need the fastest possible way to clear out the socket and get back to other things.